# LinkedHashMap serialization/deserialization

Tags: java, rest, dictionary, jackson, linkedhashmap

I have a 
`Map<Integer,List<SomeObject> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,List<SomeObject>>();` 
I was added elements in this order :

```
map.put(32,List Of SomeObjects);
map.put(2,List Of SomeObjects);
map.put(3,List Of SomeObjects);
```

after invoking this method via URL (Using restApi) I got map key in this order :

```
{2,List Of SomeObjects}
{3,List Of SomeObjects}
{32,List Of SomeObjects}
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem ?  Order of output is not order of input

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Is it the different ordering?

Comment: Order of output is not order of input

Comment: Use a [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html).

Comment: I don't want output to be sorted. I want output in that order which is input

Comment: I will use my telepathic powers and guess that what the OP means is that he is invoking a REST method to which he passes the entire list (not a different invocation for each item), and in the process the rest API reorders the list. Otherwise it makes little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap%28int,%20float,%20boolean%29)

set the boolean to false

Comment: In Java's console output is same as input , but when using URL there is problem

Comment: I do not understand your comment.

Comment: This won't help - insertion order (what you get if you pass `false`) is the default for the other constructors.

Comment: @IanRoberts Thanks Ian.  Waiting for further explanation from the OP.